# Creating Android GUI

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-gui

I am quite newbe as Android developer so I would like to ask you about good behaviours when creating Android GUI.

Mainly I have a problem with designing GUI using Relative or Linear layout because my GUI is graphical. Developing all dependencies, what should be where and what is the distance between given elements is very hard.

What your advices to create a GUI? What is being used by people designing for example Soundhound / Shazzam? How to make my GUI good looking? (I have very nice graphic but how to apply it?)

Any Frameworks to do that smooth?

Comment: No research effort!! In my career of two years as a Droid programmer I have hardly used anything else from RelativeLayout. It is the best for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager to add swiping among screens.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is... just because you use one top of layout doesn't mean you can't use multiple. Don't be afraid to mix different types of layouts, nest them and create spacebetween them. 
Android also has some nice design principles here: https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html

Comment: What about movable elements? When I am using RelativeLayout if the position of the movable element change the position of the rest will change as well.

Comment: Yep, as the name suggests the layout is relative to everything else. You can use factors like android:layout_below="@+id/post_coord_text" to do this. Some updates would be nice as well by the way, you've had two good answers here.

Comment: Ok, so how can I use RelativeLayout where I would like to have elements which are "frozen" and some of them which I can use as movable ones?

Comment: I'm not sure you wording your question entirely well. There is a wealth of documentation that Android provide, please refer to this.

Comment: Question in short: What is the best layout type when I am thinking about movable elements (for example moving from one place to another without changing position of others)?

Comment: LinearLayout for fixed and relative layout for not.